# Android ViewModel architecture for inter fragment communication

Tags: android

Over the years Android has really grown!

I only recently stumbled upon Android ViewModel.

My question is like this, everyone suggests that you have a SharedViewModel to properly design the inter-fragment communication. However isn't this bad design, because after all the benefits that ViewModel gives you it really is just a more refined type of global state.

Is this really how it works or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However isn't this bad design, because after all the benefits that ViewModel gives you it really is just a more refined type of global state.

Well, is it really "global state" though? That usually implies that the data in question:

1. Is accessible *everywhere*.
2. Is accessible by *anything*.
3. Is accessible at *any time*.

A shared viewmodel:

1. Is only accessible where the Activity it's associated with is accessible.
2. Is only accessible by the Activity it's associated with and things that can access it (sub-fragments).
3. Is only accessible during the lifecycle of the Activity.

So for example - supposed you have a `MainActivity` and a `AboutActivity`, each with a `ViewModel` (`MainViewModel` and `AboutViewModel`). `MainActivity` would have no knowledge of `AboutViewModel` and `AboutActivity` would have no knowledge of `MainViewModel`. In contrast, however, all of those classes could have access to the app's default `SharedPreferences` - now *there's* some global state for you.

Each Activity's sub-fragments can access their respective shared ViewModel, but that's not "global state" - that's an implementation detail to get them to communicate. It's basically a version of the [Mediator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) at play.

> Is this really how it works or is there a better way?

For the specific task of communicating between two fragments within the same Activity, I believe this is the best we have right now. Ultimately the fragments have to communicate *somehow* and the shared data has to live *somewhere*. Given the complexities with Fragments and Activities, the shared ViewModel pattern provides the easiest, safest, and cleanest way to solve that problem.

If you think that's bad, before you would have to go up and through the Activity which was cumbersome at best:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

*:shudder:*

Hope that helps!